# How to start CMD.exe for avd command and write function to close to specified cmd.exe

Tags: c#

Hello like in title I cant start command via C# Visual studio and CMD.exe arguments:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "C:\\Users\\obik1\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\emulator\\emulator -avd TEST_TEST";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

It works via manually put command but not via C#

Comment: Sidenote, why not use the emulator path as the FileName? Do you really need the cmd to open the emulator?

Comment: I have 10 emu names, u need call which one u need turn on

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "C:\\Users\\obik1\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\emulator\\emulator -avd TEST_TEST");
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
        var proc = Process.Start(psi);
```

tested this one and same.. :(

Comment: Don't answer youself to add more info, just edit the question :)